# iPhone, APNS usage

Tags: iphone

I have a question about APNS.

My iPhone lost, I know deviceToken, I have push some message to my iPhone, I want know if the iPhone OS was restore or reset, your know, all app will be removed includes my app,

If so, whether the push message will be send to my iPhone?

Sorry I have no other iPhone to test now. Maybe have other good idea to touch the holder of my iPhone .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No message will be processed on the device if the application for the notification no longer exists. As to whether or not restoring the phone automatically un-registers that device id for notifications for all of the applications it previously had, you will have to ask Apple. If not, the APNs servers may attempt to send the notification before realizing the app is not present.

In any case, the user will see no evidence of the notification being sent.

re: attempting to contact holder of your phone: Have you tried calling it? :-)

Comment: how to contact Apple ? from any web url ?

Comment: so, if the app removed, the notification can not be send to the iPhone ? I think it is , but I do not want it is true